# Trying to pass input value as new object into an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a simple library app with javascript. Right now I'm working on          getting the input values of the form to pass into the myLibrary array with a constructor function    when I submit the form. I've hit a wall as nothing is passing into the array and I'm unsure if my form isn't submitting or if something else is off. If anyone could give me an idea of where I might be going wrong that would awesome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>My Virtual Library</title>
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <h1>My Virtual Library</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="add-book-btn">+ Add Book</button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-overlay">
    <form id="form" class="modal">
      <h2>Add new book</h2>
      <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" required>
      <input id="author" type="text" placeholder="Author" required>
      <input id="pages" type="number" placeholder="Pages" required>
      <div class="check-container">
      <label>Have you read it?</label>
      <input id="isRead" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <input class="submit" type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
const pages = document.querySelector('#pages').value;
const isRead = document.querySelector('#isRead').value;
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
form.addEventListener('submit', addBookToLibrary);


const addBookBtn = document.querySelector('.add-book-btn');
const modalOverlay = document.querySelector('.modal-overlay');
addBookBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modalOverlay.classList.add('overlay-active');
});

let myLibrary = [

];

function Book(title, author, pages, isRead) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.isRead = false;
}

function addBookToLibrary() {
  const newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, isRead);
  myLibrary.push(newBook);
}
```

Comment: `const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;` captures the value of `title` on page load - it does not change when an input is entered ... use `const title = document.querySelector('#title');` instead, then `title.value` instead of `title`

Comment: Or just move the 4 first `const` inside the `addBookToLibrary` function.

Answer (score 2):

On the script tag, you are fetching the value as soon as the page loads and not at the time of the form submitting. Fetch the value inside at the time form loads and you will be able to see the value. So, do the following changes at the starting of the JS file

```
const title = document.querySelector('#title');
const author = document.querySelector('#author');
const pages = document.querySelector('#pages');
const isRead = document.querySelector('#isRead');
```

and inside the function

```
function addBookToLibrary() {
 const newBook = new Book(title.value, author.value, pages.value, isRead.value);
  myLibrary.push(newBook);
}
```

You can check the value getting added into the myLibrary by console logging it out in the function at the end.

```
console.log(myLibrary);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. What happens now is each time I enter something in the form I see a new object being made in the console as I type. But when I submit the form it's not console logging it or pushing anything into the array. I check after hitting submit and the array is still empty.

Comment: @CodeNoob91 This definitely works I have tested it out you must be making some mistake. Did you stop the form from refreshing onSubmit by using `event.prevenDefault()`

Comment: Yea I actually realized right after posting that comment that I hadn’t used preventDefault( ) lol. Thank you for the help!